# Acrobat reader plugin in Ubuntu 22.04, via snap

Tags: snap, adobe-acrobat

I successfully managed to install Acrobat Reader DC (file version 21.007) on Ubuntu 22.04 via snap:
`sudo snap install acrordrdc`

Now, I need to install a plugin called "FileOpen", found here
[FileOpen](https://plugin.fileopen.com/?type=Filter&name=FOPN_foweb)

From the website I can download the .exe installer.
I've no idea how to install it. I guess it should be done with snap, to maintain the coherence with Acrobat, but not sure (I read [here](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy/) that "Snap install both Wine and Adobe reader in an isolated environment").

Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks for assistance,
Valerio

Comment: Did you manage to install FileOpen?